# How to disable dates between fromdate,todate in datepicker

Tags: jquery, date, datepicker

I want to disable all dates in date picker. And want to enable date between particular two dates. for example fromdate, todate. Am using pickadate.js for display responsive date display.

```
 picker1.set('disable', [
        [2014,2,22],
        [2014,2,24]
]);
```

this list of array want to be like

```
{ from: [2014,2,22], to: [2014,2,24] }
```

here i link the source that i tried to disable, enable dates. Help me to do this
[You can see source here](http://jsfiddle.net/7BSe3/5/)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to disable dates not in a particular range. For this, you have to identify how many dates should be shown and from that you can restrict them. For example, you can set it as only one last week is enabled on fromDate:

```
$("#fromDate").datepicker({ minDate: "-7d" }).val();
```

And one next date enable on toDate:

```
$("#toDate").datepicker({ maxDate: "+ 1D" }).val();
```

More information about min/max dates [here](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/9229/)